# UISegmentedControl value changed programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

How can I hook up my UISegmentedControl's value changed method programmatically. I know it's possible using IB but I was wondering how to do it with code. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Attach a **target-action** for the control event `UIControlEventValueChanged`.

**Example**

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the addTarget:action:forControlEvents method.

```
UISegmentControl *mySegmentedControl = [UISegmentControl ...];
[mySegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```